# Managing Playwright browser binaries in Artifactory

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, artifactory, playwright

I want to be able to upload browser binaries to an Artifactory repository, so that Playwright tests can be  run against our builds in our gitlab CI pipeline, as described [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/installation#download-from-artifact-repository). I installed Playwright locally using npm via a windows terminal `npm ci -D playwright`.  I now have browser binaries for chromium, firefox and webkit located at `./AppData/local/ms-playwright`.  The problem is that the browser 'binaries' are in fact folders, and I'm not able to deploy them to Artifactory as is.  In what format should these binaries be deployed to artifactory, so that I can point to the repo in my gitlab-ci.yml file as part of the CI pipeline build process?

Comment: How do you need to consume them? as npm packages?

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky I want to be able to set PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=my/artifactory/repo  I don't have a preference on how they need to be consumed, as long as playwright will accept them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For playwright to download the browser binaries from Artifactory you will need to:

- Create a new generic [local repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Local+Repositories) in Artifactory named playwright (or any other name)
- Upload the required browser binaries to the newly created playwright repository. You can use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles), [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact) or [UI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Deploying+Artifacts) for uploading the binaries. Make sure you upload the binary to path where playwright expects it to be, for example:

[image]

- Set the playwright [PLAYWRIGHT_DOWNLOAD_HOST](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/dd3d49339d1e39ee8711abaf4ebe310d094aae3a/docs/installation.md#download-from-artifact-repository) to the the Artifactory playwright repository URL, for example:

  PLAYWRIGHT_DOWNLOAD_HOST=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/playwright npm i -D playwright